# Change the color of tag dynamically

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I m using [tag manager jQuery plugin](https://maxfavilli.com/jquery-tag-manager).

I want change the color of tag depending on validation, here is my code.
In particular, on ajax success and if `data` is defined, I want to change the color of tag.

```
jQuery('.attendees').tagsManager({
            prefilled: [user_email],
            hiddenTagListName: 'attendee',
            delimiters: [32, 44, 13, 9], // comma, space (ASCII chars)
            blinkBGColor_1: '#FFFF9C',
            blinkBGColor_2: '#c5eefa',
            validator: function (value) {
                var emailReg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/;

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'CheckUserExits',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: {email: value},
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                       alert(data);
                       if(data){
                           //I want to change the color of tag
                       }
                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {

                    }

                });

                return emailReg.test(value);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about it But you should do this.

```
<input  type="text" name="tags" placeholder="Tags" class="tm-input"/>
$(".tm-input").attr('style', 'Background-color:green;');
```

Try this but i'm not sure it will work or not.

Comment: I think he wants to change the color of the last tag, not of the input field

Answer (score 0):

```
 for error addclass`tm-tag-error` 
 for success addclass`tm-tag-success`
```

Answer (score 0):

On success you should find the tag (class `tm-tag`) you are validating and add a proper class, in order to style it with CSS.

```
   success: function (data) {
             if(data){
                var $validatingTag =  $('.attendees').find('.tm-tag:contains("'+value+'")');
                $validatingTag.addClass('tm-tag-success');
                //or any other class you want :)
               }
           },
```